# Context Menus: ellipses used at the end of certain actions

Tags: user-interface, menu, label, menuitem, ellipsis

In the various menus throughout Visual Studio Code, whether from the application menu or right-clicking from the View section (Context Menu - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/context-menus), specific actions have an ellipsis "..." at the end.

What is the official requirement for when we should include the ellipsis? And where can I find documentation around it?

Thank you!
David